# Create new non-duplication sequence in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, permutation

[ problem ]

John, who created a sequence barcode consisting of only 1, 2, and 3, wants to re-create an algorithm that creates a new sequence barcode that is different from the existing one as the number of objects increases.
When you say that you have to choose M from the natural numbers from 1 to N without redundancy, and that the length should be M, create a function that returns all the barcodes you can make in an array.
Conditional sequences must be output in order that increases in the order of dictionary.The barcode must be returned to numbers.

[ input ]

Factor 1: Natural number of the nNumber type from 1 to 10
Factor 2: Natural number of mNumber type from 1 to n
$ You must return an array containing the output number list.

[ input-output example ]

All barcodes should not have the same number.

- N is 2 and M is 1, you must use 1 or 2 to create a barcode that fits the length of 1.
  construct1 = test2 (2, 1);
  console.log(output1); // --> [1, 2]
- N is 3 and M is 2, you must create a barcode that fits the length of 2 using 1, 2, and 3.
  construct2 = test2 (3, 2);
  console.log(output2); //-> [12, 13, 21, 23, 31, 32]

**This is the code I wrote.**

```
function solution(m, arr){         
    let answer=[];
    n=arr.length;
    let ch=Array.from({length:n},()=>0);
    let tmp=Array.from({length:m},()=>0);
    function DFS(L){
        if(L===m){
            answer.push(tmp.slice());
        }
        else{
            for(let i=0; i<n; i++){
                if(ch[i]===0){
                    ch[i]=1;
                    tmp[L]=arr[i];
                    DFS(L+1);
                    ch[i]=0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    DFS(0);
    return answer;
}

let arr=[3, 6, 9];
console.log(solution(2, arr));
```

**As you can see from the code, unlike the factors required in the problem, I put the array into the factor.
But I want to input natural numbers and output them in an array, as I do in an input-output example.
What is the good way to solve this problem?**

Comment: I'm not entirely following the question (am I right that you used an automatic translation to English for this?)  But if the question is how to take, say, the natural number `4`, and turn it into the array `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, then you can search for `range` functions.  They are fairly easy to write.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer to your question is that you can use a `range` function, which given a start and finish natural number returns the array that include all integers between them (including their endpoints.)  We could write one like this:

```js
const range = (low, high) =>
  [...Array (high - low + 1)].map ((_, i) => i + low)
```

Then we can call `range(1, 4)` to get `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.  While we could skip the `low` parameter, the function is more useful like this, as we can use it for, say, `range(3, 12) //=> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]`.

Your version would only take this minimal change:

```js
function solution(m, arr){         
    let answer=[];
// ...
```

becomes

```js
function solution(m, n){
    let arr = range(1, n);         
    let answer=[];
// ...
```

(although I think the parameter order might not match the expectations.)

---

But I think your instincts are correct here.  The function you wrote has a more useful API than what's asked for.  I would suggest that you rename `solution` as it is to something else, say `words`, and then write a simple new `solution` that takes `m` and `n`, and calls it.

```js
function solution (m, n) {
  return words (m, range (1, n))
}
```

---

Here is another version of the same idea, using a recursive version of `words`:

```js
const range = (lo, hi) =>
  [...Array (hi - lo + 1)].map ((_, i) => i + lo)

const excluding = (n) => (xs) =>
  xs .filter (x => x != n)

const words = (alphabet, length) =>
  length == 0
    ? []
  : length == 1
    ? alphabet .map (String)
  : alphabet .flatMap (a => words (excluding (a) (alphabet), length - 1) .map (w =>a + String(w)))

const barcodes = (n, m) => 
  words (range (1, n), m)

console .log (barcodes (2, 1)) //=> ["1", "2"]
console .log (barcodes (3, 2)) //=> ["12", "13", "21", "23", "31", "32"]
console .log (barcodes (4, 2)) //=> ["12", "13", "14", "21", "23", "24", 
                               //    "31", "32", "34", "41", "42", "43"]
console .log (barcodes (4, 3)) //=> ["123", "124", "132", "134", "142", "143", "213", "214", 
                               //    "231", "234", "241", "243", "312", "314", "321", "324", 
                               //    "341", "342", "412", "413", "421", "423", "431", "432"]
console .log (barcodes (0, 3)) //=> []
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Comment: Sauyet It seems a little difficult to understand right now, but I will study to understand it by looking at the code you wrote.
Thank you very much for answering the question.

Comment: If you have questions about this, feel free to ask here in the comments.